# Why 888888888888888888888 equals 888888888888888900000 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why 888888888888888888888 equals 888888888888888900000 in JavaScript

```js
console.log(888888888888888888888 === 888888888888888900000)
```

in chrome console

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin/307194#307194

Comment: Also this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Comment: Try: `888888888888888888888n === 888888888888888900000n`

Answer (score 1):

That is because integers can only be precisely represented in JavaScript up to 2^53 - 1

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

The problem is that, after 2^53 - 1, there is not enough bits to represent the number. So, when you set a higher number, you lose information and what you are actually storing in memory is not reliable. In your case, these 2 numbers, after converting to binary, are the same. That is why they are equal